# Delphi TFileListBox: Appearance of the icons of GoogleDrive

Tags: delphi, synchronization, google-drive-api

[image]How can I get the same look (different icon) for a folder and GoogleDrive TFileLstBox?

Comment: Why are you using TFileListBox? It's not a very good control.

Comment: I get the same result with jvFileListBox or TShellListView

Comment: So you want to pretend that the Google drive folder is actually a directory? You'll need to code that yourself.

Comment: I want the check symbol to icon

Comment: Surprising the shell list view doesn't draw the overlay icons